# How do I determine how well a person does on average compared to previous work done in their same position?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I'm currently leading a group of missionaries and I want to find out how well each missionary is doing compared to the average in their area. Each area has a historical data of how well it's performed. Let's say one of the recorded statistics is new people met. I've calculated:

- The Average number of new people met in the specific area
- Standard deviation of new people met in the specific area
- The Z-Score of each week for new people met of the current missionary in the specific area, assuming a normal distribution

I now want to calculate on average how well the current missionary performs above or below the mean in their specific area. I've tried averaging the missionary's Z-scores, but I don't think it's giving me any useful information so far. What would be a better method of calculating a missionary's impact on their area? Maybe a t-test?

Comment: Could you tell us some more? How large is the dataset? How do you measure missionaries performance? Are they doing better than reported in the marvelous book https://www.amazon.co.uk/Dont-Sleep-There-are-Snakes/dp/1846680409/ref=sr_1_1?crid=11LNDJFUT9JX0&keywords=dont+sleep+there+are+snakes&qid=1706278780&sprefix=dont+sleep+there+are+snakes%2Caps%2C358&sr=8-1